# Supported sample rates in Windows

Tags: c, windows, audio

I'm working on a music player on Windows, and I'm using the `waveOutOpen` (with friends) API. To specify the format of the audio data I fill out the `WAVEFORMATEX` structure, specifying the correct `wFormatTag`. However, I recently learned that there exists audio files with a sample rate of 88.2 kHz. That is not among the available `WAVE_FORMAT_*`, which puzzles me.

Assuming the DAC being used supports 88.2 kHz input, how can that be used on Windows? And what about even higher sample rates like 192 kHz which is also not among the `WAVE_FORMAT_*` values? I see that there's `WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE` which as far as I can tell allows for specifying a higher bits per sample value, but what about higher sample rates?

In my "Speaker Properties" I see that my system supports 24-bit 192 kHz audio, but how would one provide data at that sample rate on Windows?

Comment: I think the `WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT` can actually support mentioned sample rates.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if `WAVE_FORMAT_*` aren't really useful. They are referred to as standard formats in `WAVEOUTCAPS`'s description of `dwFormats`. And I found this quote `To see whether a device supports a particular format (standard or nonstandard), you can call the waveOutOpen function with the WAVE_FORMAT_QUERY flag.` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/determining-nonstandard-format-support).

So I wonder if I just need to try and open the device with the settings I want, and check if it supports it...

Comment: It does however seem that `WAVE_FORMAT_PCM` only supports 8- or 16-bit samples, so if I e.g. have 24-bit 88.2 kHz audio, I'd need to use `WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT` and specify how many of the 32 bits through `WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE.wValidBitsPerSample`.